# How to Add Values to Combo Box

Tags: vb.net

I want to Add Values to my combobox in Datareader.
This is my code,

```
Command = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id = '" & id & "')

Command.CommandTimeout = 30
dr = Command.ExecuteReader()
If Reader.HasRows = True Then
    While Reader.Read()
        cmb.Items(dr(0))
    End While
End If
```

I have tried adding it this way but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this
`cmb.Items.add(dr(0))`.
And be precise in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

While dr.read() use this ...instead of Reader.Read()